Table partitioning for CDC enabled table
Is there any issue you have faced enabling table partitioning for CDC enabled tables?
I have done some quick testing and table partitioning for CDC enabled tables is working well in terms of switching data. I understand, I cannot use truncate on the table or a partition while CDC is enabled:
TRUNCATE TABLE schema.tablename WITH (PARTITIONS (22));

Msg 4711, Level 16, State 1, Line 96
Cannot truncate table because it is published for replication 
or enabled for Change Data Capture.

I am not sure, is it ok to disable CDC before the truncate and then enable it again? Or will that cause issues for existing CDC data capture?
I believe I can back up the CDC table before disabling, do the truncate and then enable it again. Since truncate partition is done once monthly.
I would like to get experienced people's suggestions before implementing in production.
